# invalid operands of void in recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, void

I'm trying to split the number using recursion e.g 123 into 12,3. So I have a problem because I used `void` and now compilator shows :

> invalid operands of types 'void' and 'int' to binary 'operator !='

In the last line where the recursion is.
I assume it's about `a` and `b` comparison in the beginning but `a` and `b` are `int` types so I don't understand why I can't compare them to `zero`.

```
void podzial ( int N, int a, int b, int & k )
{
if(N==0 and a!=0 and b!=0)
    if(prime(a,b))
    {
        cout<<a<<b<<endl;
        k++;
    }
else if(N==0) return;
else
{
    a*=10; b*=10;
    podzial(N/10,a+(N%10),b,k) or podzial(N/10,a,b+(N%10),k);
}
}
```

Comment: You may want to add additional `{}` to make it clear which `if`s go with which `else`s. At the moment it is hard to tell what branches you want

Comment: [I see a different error](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/0b341e318115c7c4)

Comment: Please explain what you want the last line to do (the longest line)

Comment: Yes, thanks Caleth because actually this `else` went to wrong `if` as I see now.

Comment: I wanted to add the last digit of N ( the number I split) to a or b but I realize that I make two identical splits so one `podzial` is enough but in the first run I have to choose which one will have the last digit of N

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`podzial` has a `void` return value, so can't be used as an argument in an `or` (i.e. `||`) conditional check.

Didn't you want the function to return an `int`?

Bear in mind too that `or` is short-circuited, so the right hand side will not be evaluated if the left hand side evaluates to `true`.

Comment: If you want to use it in a conditional expression it should return '''bool'''

Comment: @RobertAndrzejuk Or implicitly convertible to bool.

Comment: If the result returned is a integer value then integer type should be returned. But if the result is a '''true''' or '''false''' then only a bool should be used. By design, the result type should not be based on implicit conversions.

Comment: Thanks! Now, of course I see that I can't do `or` here. Yes, in the end it is supossed to return the value of k but I didn't know where I should initialize `int k=0` because it's recursion so I decided to make `int & k` and make another function which returns k

Answer (score 0):

```
void podzial (int N, int a, int b, int& k) {
    ...
    else if(N == 0) {
        return;   // Should't have a return here since podzial's return type is void.
                  // 
                  // You can just do what I do in the code example below.
    }
    ...
```

You might want to reorganize your if statements...

```
void podzial (int N, int a, int b, int& k) {
    if(N == 0) {
        if(a != 0 && b != 0) {
            if(prime(a, b)) {
                cout << a << b << endl;
                k++;
            }
        }
        cout << "Recursion terminated";
    }
    else {
        a *= 10; 
        b *= 10;
        podzial( N / 10, a + (N % 10), b, k)
        // or podzial(N / 10, a, b + (N % 10), k);
        // If you actually wanted to write...
        // return podzial(...) || podzial(....)
        // Then you'll need to add a return type to the function header
        // and can keep the 'else if(N==0) return 0;'
    }
}
```

With the void return type, if you don't want to recurse further, make sure to have your termination clause be the only thing that runs on the final iteration (one giant if/else statement).